# Using R.Java in Titanium module

Tags: java, android, titanium, r.java-file

I need to start an activity in my titanium module.Then I have to setContent of my Layout in my pure java code, But I cannot locate the layout file in Titanium module.

I used below code but i get error that file not found.

```
int id =  TiRHelper.getApplicationResource("layout.activity_main");
```

If i put my layout files inside "platform/android/res" i get error,any idea to help me?

```
invalid resource directory name:
[ERROR] Error generating R.java from manifest
```

Regards

Comment: if you need to run pure java code - why not build a module?

Comment: I found that the layout folder should be copied to the platform/android/res/layout inside the module not inside titanium project. the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Might have nothing to do with it but I once ran across this problem and solved by putting the application id in the `com.company.app` format

Answer (score 0):

If your XML's contain errors your generated file might not build try erasing most of their content and making sure id's and file names are not duplicated and no capitals and spaces are used. If it works you can start adding stuff.

(or)

You're importing invalid R class I Think, 
import yourpackage.R class
for example
com.example.R

what actully happends that u import android.R class not yourpackages.R

Comment: i checked the R, its true. I think my problem is that I didnt locate my xml file in a right place? where should i copy them? i cannot put them inside platform/android because i get "Error generating R.java from manifest"?